# Can a fee in Ether be added to ERC20 Token transfers

Tags: ether, erc-20, fees, address.transfer

New to Solidity...

Is it possible to have a fee for transfers of an ERC20 Token in Ether? The fee would be 0.000001 Ether per transfer. Each time the ERC20 Token is sent to another user, the fee in Ether would be sent to a contract. Source example of how to transfer the fee in ether would be most helpful.

(note: this question does not pertain to gas fees. This refers to an additional fee in Ether for transfers of an ERC20 Token.)

Comment: ERC20 is a standard, nothing prevents you from overloading its functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the specifications set out by the [ERC-20 standard here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md).

For the relevant functions, `transfer` and `transferFrom`, there is no mention of mutability restrictions (or for any other function).

If you made these functions `payable`, and required that the value be 0.000001 ETH, it probably wouldn't be breaching the ERC-20 standard (as laid out by this document).

Comment: Can a payable function implement a non-payable function?

Comment: What do you mean by implement? A payable function can call a non-payable function. There is no mention in the standard of restrictions against being payable, and presumably if it were restricted they would have used the explicit nonpayable modifier.

Comment: The EIP20 is an interface which has functions which the interface implementation must implement. `transfer` is one of those functions so the implementing contract has to have a `transfer` function with the same signature. If a `payable` function can implement the function in the interface, then my answer is incorrect. But I couldn't find much info about this :(

Comment: Actually this is a good point, if the payable modifier is added to a function will the signature be different? I suspect it will, which probably means you're right.

Comment: No, adding `payable` doesn't change the function hash. The function hash is simply the hash of `transfer(address,uint256)` (or `bytes4(keccak256("transfer(address,uint256)"))`, which is `0xa9059cbb`), no return values, modifiers or mutability are considered for the function hash.

Comment: I was just trying this in remix and gives type error:contract A {
    function doit() public;
}
contract B is A {
    function doit() payable public {
    }
}

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ER20 standard though, this is just an error caused because you're inheriting from another contract and then overwriting with a function with different mutability. But the ERC20 standard isn't a contract, it's a set of specifications that your own contract must meet (see the link in my answer). You may find examples of contracts that *meet* the ERC20 standard, but they are not the standard itself. So this error isn't related to the ERC20 issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the ERC20 standard(https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard), the answer is no.

But nothing stops you from extending the functionality. Extending it simply means that it has extra functionality on top of regular ERC20 functionality - users have to know about the extra functionality to be able to use it.

Here's one pretty standard implementation of a ERC20 token: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol
If we look at the `transfer` function, we can add a similar function for example like this:

```
function transferWithFee(address _to, uint256 _value) public payable returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        // require some amount of ether to be included in the transaction.
        require(msg.value >= 123);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

All Ether sent to the function stays in the contract. Also you probably want to do something nasty to the original `transfer` function so people don't just use that but use this new function: you can for example just implement it as:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return false;
    }
```